# The Sh’ma in kabbalah and chasiduss

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, shema

Are there any kabbalistic and Hasidic interpretations or meanings given to the Sh’ma? If so, what are they? Preferably both kabbalah and chasiduss references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Nefesh Hachaim Shaar 3 chapter 11 and also see Tanya in Shaar Hayichud Vemuna chapters 6&7 where they say a similar idea. The Tetragrammaton which refers to G-D’s essence (in which from his perspective there is absolute oneness and nothing else exists but him), is one and the same as the name Elokeinu which from our perspective we see differentiation and various forces that all stem from G-d.